# How should I represent a single unicode character in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

I would like to represent a single Unicode character in Java. Which primitive or class that is appropriate for this?

Note that I want to be able to store any unicode character, which may be too large for a 2 byte `char`.

Comment: You can use `char`

Comment: `char ch = '\u1111';`

Comment: @prasanth: `char` can't hold all Unicode characters. `char` basically corresponds to a UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I want to store any character that might be in a unicode string. As I understand it, `char` is 2 bytes, which may be too small.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`char` is indeed 16-bit, [a `char` corresponds to a UTF-16 *code unit*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1). Characters that don't fit in a single UTF-16 code unit (Emojis, for instance) require two `char`s.

If you need to store them individually for some reason, you can use an `int` for that. It has sufficient room (and then some) for all of the 0x10FFFF code points currently allowed in Unicode. That's what the JDK uses, for instance in [`Character.codePointAt(CharSequence seq, int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt-java.lang.CharSequence-int-) and [`String(int[] codePoints, int offset, int count)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-int:A-int-int-).

Gratuitous conversion example ([live on ideone](http://ideone.com/abiCwd)):

```
String s = "";
int emoji = Character.codePointAt(s, 0);
String unumber = "U+" + Integer.toHexString(emoji).toUpperCase();
System.out.println(s + "  is code point " + unumber);
String s2 = new String(new int[] { emoji }, 0, 1);
System.out.println("Code point " + unumber + " converted back to string: " + s2);
System.out.println("Successful round-trip? " + s.equals(s2));
```

which outputs:

```
  is code point U+1F602
Code point U+1F602 converted back to string: 
Successful round-trip? true
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the definition of a character:

If you mean one single *Unicode code point*, use `int`, which can hold every value from U+0000 to U+1FFFFF.

However, in some cases what appears as one character occupies multiple code points. This is especially common with emoji, eg.

- [skin tone](http://emojipedia.org/modifiers/):
- [country flags](http://emojipedia.org/flags/):
- [families](http://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl-boy/): ‍‍‍, which becomes `"+++"` if I replace the zero-width joiners (U+200D) with plus signs.

To store those the most logic way is using a `String`.

Comment: You can find the list of all emoji in string/int format in **#EmojiCodeSheet** [here](https://github.com/shanraisshan/EmojiCodeSheet)